# How to display records based on selected year from dropdown dynamically without any submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on PHP code-igniter.

My view code goes like below:

```
<form method="post" action="">  
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
        <div class="form-group">                            
            <label class="h5" for="Mode"><b>See year wise commitments</b></label>
            <select class="form-control" name="Year" id="Year"  onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="">Select Year</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Just by selecting any year from dropdown, I have to pass the selected year to my controller and inturn to model and get the query results based on the selected year.

In my controller I am receiving the posted value like:

```
$selectedYear = $this->input->post('Year');
```

And before selecting any dropdown value the records in my view has to be of Current year.

My ajax code is

```
$( "#year" ).change(function() {
    year = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
          url : "controllerfilename/controllername",
          data : {"year": year},
          type : "post",
          success: function(data){
             console.log(data);
          }
   });
```

});

Comment: can you update your ajax code here?

Comment: Updated my ajax code

Comment: check the updated answer..

Answer (score 3):

You can make an ajax call to your controller on change function of dropdown

```
    $( "#year" ).change(function() {
        year = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
              url : "controller url",
              data : {"year": year},
              type : "post",
              success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
              }
       });
   });
```

Comment: no errors, but i m not receiving any selected year in my controller

Answer (score 0):

You defined **id** as `id="Year"` but in the **ajax** you call it like `$( "#year" ).change(function() {`. Means In ajax its `year` and in view its `Year` (uppercase).

Try this code:

```
$("#Year").change(function() {
year = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
      url : "<?php echo base_url('controllerfilename/controllername') ?>",
      data : {"year": year},
      type : "post",
      success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
      }
});
});
```